# Select every even item after 4

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I'm wondering if its possible to selected every even item after the 4th item using the CSS nth-child selector.

Below is what I have so far? Any ideas

**scss**

```
.project{
    @include span-columns(4 of 8);
    @include omega(2n);
    height: 580px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    &:first-child{
        margin-top: 55px;
    }

    &:nth-child(n+4){
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`:nth-child(2n+6)` will match every other item starting with the 6th item.

```css
div:nth-child(2n+6) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
<div>blah</div>
```

Comment: I want to match every even item after 4th element

Comment: @samsos oops! Missed the word "even" in your question. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to select every second item after the fourth item, you're looking for `:nth-child(2n+6)` :)

```css
div:nth-child(2n+6) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
<div>Test</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div:nth-child(2n+6) {
  color:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
```